# Using Orchard CMS is it possible to build an interface for fast list entry?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm digging into orchard CMS, but I'm a little bit skeptical that I might not have the ability to do something like create new content items quickly without posting back to the server.

For example. Let's say I define a content type for a product. One property a product might have is a collection of variations or similar products that can maybe be sorted by relevance. (Think a comic book with variant covers)

Could you build an interface for this where you enter a new product, and search for and include multiple variant products all from the same client interface without ever having to post back or do a hard page refresh?

I guess maybe, what I'm really asking is if it would be easy to expose the content through Web API or something like that, and from there you can really just build anything.

I'm a little worried about starting down the road of using a nice framework like this, only to find half-way through that I'm limited by the framework itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about OrchardCMS as a super set of ASP.NET MVC. You can build a custom controller to handle your own types or even content types (see OrchardServices)

In your case, just make a custom controller which will handle via actions the ajaxs requests to create, update, get related items and so on.

You should read the Sipke post series, in particularly this one: (http://skywalkersoftwaredevelopment.net/blog/writing-an-orchard-webshop-module-from-scratch-part-6) Another useful resource is the course of pluralsight.

Comment: Thanks, since this I've dug into it quite a bit more, and the reality is that I can do anything I want. The CMS provides a lot of nice jump starts, and a nice management framework, but it doesn't "block" anything at all really.